# getsizeof() function returns different output in Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, boolean, sizeof

Small code:

```
import sys

x = True

print(sys.getsizeof(x))
```

**Python 2 output:**

```
24
```

**Python 3 output:**

```
28
```

Why does outputs of `getsizeof()` function different in Python 2 and Python 3?

Comment: Because the size of `True` in memory appears to be 4 bytes larger in Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For built-in types, `sys.getsizeof()` returns basically an *implementation detail* of the Python implementation you are using.

This means that, *even for the same Python version*, you might see different sizes for different implementations/platforms/builds... Therefore, you cannot rely on specific answers – and much less expect them to stay constant!

Finally, note that `sys.getsizeof()` is not an operator; it is simply a function of the `sys` module.

Answer (score 3):

On both Python 2 and Python 3, `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and `True == 1`. However, on Python 3, `int` is the equivalent of Python 2 `long`, and it stores integers in an arbitrary-precision representation.

On the build of Python 3 you're running, that representation happens to take 4 more bytes to store the value 1 than what the `int` representation takes on your Python 2 build, most likely due to the `ob_size` field that stores the length of the arbitrary-precision representation.

If this ever actually matters to a program you write, you're probably doing something really crazy, and/or misusing `getsizeof`.

Comment: You seems to have more clearer answer! Thanks for your comment! :D